# In custom header consist two items title and button, while clicking on button new activity has to open

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In am trying for hot star like video streaming app, in recyclerview i am having header_layout and Item_layout in header_layout i am having two fields textview and button now my question is while clicking the button it has to go next activity. how can we achieve this. i am having adapter class and ViewHolder class.

### header_type_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16sp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gridHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="MORE" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

In Adapter Class

```
 private void bindHeaderItem(final Holder holder, final int position) {
        TextView title = (TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.gridHeader);
        title.setText(mListItem.get(position).getmItemTitle());

        Button button= (Button) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context,Activity2.class));
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code what have you tried till now ?

Comment: So this is not working right ?

Comment: its not working

Comment: event i tried this code in ViewHolder class also, there is also same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void bindHeaderItem(final Holder holder, final int position) {
        TextView title = (TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.gridHeader);
        title.setText(mListItem.get(position).getmItemTitle());

        Button button = (Button) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonHeader);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put all your views inside ViewHolder. It will work if everything fine.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyHolder> {
private static final String TAG = MyAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private Context mContext;
private List<Item> mItems;

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mItems = items;
}

@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.header_type_layout, parent, false);
    return new MyHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = mItems.get(position);

    bindView(holder, item);

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(v -> startYourActivity());
}

private void bindView(MyHolder holder, Item item) {
// Bind your view here
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private Button button;
    private TextView textview;

    MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(...);
        textview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(....);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i have to give other activity name in holder.button.setOnClickListener(v -> startYourActivity()); or in onClick method.

Comment: holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, YourActivity.class));
            }
        });

Comment: did same thing again same problem

Comment: Please update your question with full of your code. Activity you use recyclerView, activity you want to start, your adapter